# Exception while using LoggingAspect with Spring Cloud Data Flow Custom Sink

Tags: spring-aop, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to write custom sink in Spring Cloud Data Flow. It was all working fine. Then I introduced Logging Aspect for Logging and I started getting this issue

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyAccessorBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration$PostProcessorConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration$PostProcessorConfiguration$2]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration$PostProcessorConfiguration$2]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:468) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:349) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:345) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:55) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:203) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:413) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

By looking into it seems some jar class conflict but not able to figure out the exact problem.

Comment: Looks like your aspect is trying to advise Spring configuration classes. How's your aspect defined ?

Comment: Its a simple annotation baed logging   `@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

 @Around("execution(* *(..)) ")
 public Object employeeAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {

  System.out.println("Here...");
  Object value = null;
  try {
   value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
  } catch (Throwable e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  System.out.println("Here done...");
  return value;
 }
}`.